# Dual boot system fails to boot at all! Help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, grubrescue

I have a persistent problem of recovering my hard drive.
I had Ubuntu and Win 7 installed on my DELL xps m1530 (Core Duo 2). After manipulating my partitions in windows, I got stuck in grub rescue. I cannot remember what I had exactly done, but right now, I have `grub rescue>` command line and the list of partitions are :
`(hd0) (hd0,msdos8) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos7) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`

I have tried to get the list of files on those drives, but for all of them except `(hd0,msdos6)` and `(hd0,msdos8)`, I get the following error when trying eg. `ls (hd0,msdos7)`:

`error: unknown filesystem.`

in case of getting the list of files on `(hd0,msdos6)` or `(hd0,msdos8)` I get this error:
`error: bad filename.`
I have tried live ubuntu cd but it didn't boot and ended up with kernel panic(see below for details)
I have tried to use live usb installation of ubuntu (using LinuxLive USB Creator and Universal USB installer) but when I try to boot from USB, I get the error of Kernel Panic(see below for details on this).

I have also tried:
`set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal`
and I got the boot menu back, but I have tried all options (Normal ubuntu boot, recovery mode, fail safe mode, windows 7 ,..) and ubuntu ends up with a black screen with mouse icon only available, and windows stuck on loading animation, I have tried repair startup mode on windows and it didn't work as well.
For last try, I have tried the grub rescue   super disk (http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and it also ended up with same error of Kernel Panic:
`Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200

...
..
.
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console`

The dots in above error are some error codes I didn't have courage to type them, cause I guess they are not relevant.

My sense tells me I have somehow ruined the address table of my HDD or done something else wrong on HDD. Since I have also used diagnosing tool from Bios to check my hardware, I know I don't have any hardware problem. Also since windows gets into loading screen, this means my graphics and cpu and RAM are working fine. I am also suspecting some corrupted files that remained from an unfinished try of windows of ubuntu installation can cause the same problem.
So, my question is how can I get my HDD back, even if it needed to be completely formatted and data will be lost(Of course, it would be my last option).
Thank you for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue last night.
What I have done was to use the following commands first to get grub menu back from grub rescue:
`grub rescue> set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
 grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
 grub rescue> insmod normal
 grub rescue> normal`

After this I got to grub usual boot selection menu.
Then instead of booting to windows or ubuntu I just selected `c` to enter the grub command line and then I have used the following instructions on grub command line to (I think) repair the grub:

`grub> set root=(hd0,6)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda6
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub> boot`

I have replaced the name `vmlinuz-3.13.0...` with my own version which was `vmlinuz-3.8.0...` and also the same in line with `initrd.img-3.13.0...` which I typed `initrd.img-3.8.0...`.
The important thing was to determine the linux installation drive, then find out the correct version of above mentioned files.
I have used the latter instructions from following link and modified the file-names with my own version numbers:
http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/

Comment: Remember to vote your answer as a chosen one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I used to do this such of mess moving partitions too.
forget the grub rescue, download the grub rescue cd:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
run it in a USB stick or a cd and it will restore the boot to ubuntu automatically.

or you can use any debian-based live cd and follow these steps:
boot the live cd, chose try ubuntu/debian/etc., open a terminal and then run these commands:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

Comment: Thank you for answer @marciofao, but I had already tried out those and neither live cd nor grub rescue cd worked. I have solved the issue last night and I have posted the answer above.